# Limit at infinity / Show inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials, infinity

I am looking at the following:

1. Show that if $p,q$ are real polynomial of the same degree, then $p(x)\asymp q(x)$ as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$.
2. Show that the funcions $n^{-x}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ define an asymptotic sequence as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.
3. Show that for a big enough $X>0$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a constant $C_n>0$ such that $$\left |\int_{\mathbb{R}}\text{exp}\left (iXt-t^2\right )\, dt\right |\leq \frac{C_n}{X^n}$$

$$$$

I have done the following:

1. The limit of a polynomial at infinity is equal to $\pm \infty$, it depends on the leading coefficient, right?

   Therefore both limits, of $p$ and $q$ will be $\pm \infty$ and so it holds that $p(x)\approx q(x)$.
2. To show that it is an asymptotic sequence do we have to show that it converges?
3. Could you give me a hint? I don't really have an idea.

$$$$

**EDIT:**

As for (1):

Let's consider the definition for $p(x)\asymp  q(x)$: there are $0<A<B$ such that $A|q(x)|\leq |p(x)|\leq B|q(x)|$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$.

To show the first inequality:

Do we consider the limit $\lim\inf_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|p(x)|}{|q(x)|}$ ?

Since $\deg p=\deg q=:n$ it follows that the limit is equal to the fraction of the coefficients of $x^n$, correct?

We want to show that this limit is positive, don't we? This follows since we have the absolute value.

Is that correct?

For the second inequality:

Do we consider the limit $\lim\sup_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|p(x)|}{|q(x)|}$ ?

Since $\deg p=\deg q=:n$ it follows that the limit is equal to the fraction of the coefficients of $x^n$.

We want to show that this limit is finite ($<\infty$), don't we? This follows since we have a fraction of two real positive constants.

Is that correct?

Comment: For the first question, what, precisely, does $\approx$ mean?

Comment: I think it means equalin infinity @RobertShore

Comment: Do you have an idea? @RobertShore

Comment: What 1. means is either (1) there are positive $A, B$ such that $Aq(x)\le p(x)\le Bq(x)$ for all sufficiently large $|x|,$ or (2) if $p\ne 0\ne q$ then $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}p(x)/q(x)$ exists in $\Bbb R$.... Depending on who wrote the problem and what they meant by $\approx.$

Comment: I suspected it was something like that, which is a significantly stronger condition than just requiring that each polynomial goes to $\infty$.  So for $1$, just take the ratio $p(x)/q(x)$ and then divide top and bottom by $x^n$, where $n = \deg(p)=\deg(q)$.  Then take the limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Let's take definition (1), and more precisely : there are $0<A<B$ such that $A|q(x)|\leq |p(x)|\leq B|q(x)|$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$. To show the first inequality: Do we consider the limit $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|p(x)|}{A|q(x)|}$ ? Since $\deg p=\deg q=:n$ it follows that the limit is equal to the fraction of the coefficients of $x^n$, correct? We want to show that this limit is positive, don't we? This follows since $A>0$ and since we have the absolute value. Is that correct? @DanielWainfleet

Comment: Yes. That is correct..............